# AWS lambda image environment variables not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-sam

**I create AWS lambda using container image. However the environment variables defined in YAML is not found.**

How I create the container image

1. Use SAM to scaffold, choosing `AWS Quick Start Templates` > `Hello World Example`
2. Update `template.yaml` with environment variables
3. `sam build`
4. Push to ECR
5. Create lambda function using ECR container image

Here is the YAML I tried

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.9

  Sample SAM Template for sam_hello_world

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Environment:
      Variables:
        BUCKET_NAME: "somes3bucketname"

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./hello_world
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1
```

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.9

  Sample SAM Template for sam_hello_world

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BUCKET_NAME: "somes3bucketname"
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./hello_world
      DockerTag: python3.9-v1
```

My app.py

```py
import io
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(os.environ)
    print(os.environ["BUCKET_NAME"])
    return {"statusCode": 200}
```

However, this will throw keyerror because the environment variable is not found by os.environ.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'BUCKET_NAME'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 32, in lambda_handler\n    os.environ[\"BUCKET_NAME\"],\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 679, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In your lambda UI, do you see this environment variable, BUCKET_NAME?

Comment: No, don't see it in the UI, nor in the log returned by `print(os.environ)`

Comment: That indicates that the environment variable is not available to the lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect my steps from 3 onwards is wrong.

Basically, when `sam build` is executed, it builds the container image, but the environment variables are not added into the image itself.

The only time the `template.yaml` is taken into consideration is when you do `sam deploy`.

Comment: also commands like `sam local` and `sam package`

Comment: I've overcome this by using secrets manager and storing the env variables there. Then the first thing my lambda does is get secrets and make them env variables.